# Is there a generic way to preserve state variables on the stack in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, state

In the program I'm currently working on, a number of the objects include state variables which persist with the object.  e.g. an object representing a point in 3d model might include a variable to control whether that point has been selected for editing.  Quite regularly, one or more of these state variables will be temporarily modified by a piece of code, e.g.

```
void MyFunc();
{
  mytype temp = statevar;
  statevar = newvalue;
  DoSomething();
  statevar = temp;
}
```

This has got problems, as if `DoSomething()` throws an exception, `statevar` is not restored correctly.  My planned workaround is to create a new template class that restores the value in its dtor.  Something like

```
template<class TYPE> class PushState
{
   PushState(TYPE Var) { Temp = Var; }
   Pop() { Var = Temp; }
   ~PushState() { Pop(); }
   TYPE Temp;
}

void MyFunc();
{
   PushState<mytype> Push(statevar);
   DoSomething();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, or a well accepted method of pushing variables to the stack?

Comment: This sounds like `scope_guard`.

Comment: @Pubby Was my 1st thought too, would have voted twice if possible ...

Comment: Thanks Pubby, has to look that up.  The following DrDobbs article looks promising; http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758?

Comment: An alternative is to modify *copies* of your data instead of the original and use those, and only when you are sure that you have completed your work sucessfully move the values into their final destination using somethning that won't throw like swap.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207965/general-way-to-reset-a-member-variable-to-its-original-value-using-the-stack

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use an ad hoc RAII class.

For example:

```
void MyFunc();
{
    class Finally {
        mytype temp;
    public:
        Finally( ) { temp = statevar; }
        ~Finally() {
            statevar = temp;
        }
    } finally;

    statevar = newvalue;
    DoSomething();
}
```

Whether the function returns normally or throws an exception, the destructor is called automatically when `finally` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html). This will instantiate an object whose destructor will execute the scope exit code. It just hides all the boilerplate code for you.

```
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>

void MyFunc() {
    mytype temp = statevar;
    statevar = newvalue;
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(&statevar) {
        statevar = temp;
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
    DoSomething();
}
```