# How to reset multiple variables when going out of scope?

Tags: c++, templates, scope, c++17, class-template

I want to reset multiple variables when they go out of scope.

Currently, I have a solution for 1 variable, which is similar to given in the answers here:

[General way to reset a member variable to its original value using the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207965/general-way-to-reset-a-member-variable-to-its-original-value-using-the-stack)

```
template<typename T>
struct Context
{
    T savedValue;
    T& ref;
    Context(T& value) : savedValue(value), ref(value) {}

    ~Context()
    {
        ref = savedValue;
    }
};
#define CONCAT_(x,y) x##y
#define CONCAT(x,y) CONCAT_(x,y)
// __line__ to allow multiple
#define SAVE_CONTEXT(var) Context<decltype(var)> CONCAT(ctx, __LINE__)(var)
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct Context
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> savedValues;  // OK
    T& ref;                         // What should be the type here?
    Context(Ts... values) : {}      // How ?

    ~Context()
    {
        // ?
    }
};
#define SAVE_CONTEXT(...) ...       // ?
```

Comment: Or you can just use a scope guard with a lambda that resets the values. Scope guards are a usable tool in other situations as well.  A scope guard is a class that accepts a lambda on construction of which the lambda will be called at destructor time.

Comment: can you show an example of how you use `SAVE_CONTEXT()`? And why you don't want several of them, each for 1 variable?

Comment: There's *no way* you need macros for this.   In general; don't use macros.

Comment: "#define CONCAT_(x,y) x##y
#define CONCAT(x,y) CONCAT_(x,y)
// __line__ to allow multiple
#define SAVE_CONTEXT(var) Context<decltype(var)> CONCAT(ctx, __LINE__)(var)   
" - Ouch. That's horrible. Use variadic templates or *something* - don't use macros for that. Eeek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the issue correctly, you could achieve the same with non-MACRO ways.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename... Args> class Context
{
   std::tuple<Args...> mSavedValues; // for values
   std::tuple<Args&...> mRefs;       // for references

public:
   constexpr Context(Args&... values)
       : mSavedValues(values...)
       , mRefs(values...)
   {}

   constexpr ~Context() {
       // reset to the initial values
       mRefs = mSavedValues;
   }
};

// template "saveContext" instead of the MACRO
template<typename... Args>
constexpr Context<Args...> saveContext(Args&... values) {
   return Context<Args...>(values...);
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    float b = 2.2f;
    {
        auto ctx = saveContext(a, b);
        a = 10;
        b = 20.02f;
        // a and b will be set to 10 and 20.02f
    }
    // a and b will be reset to their original values 
    // (1 and 2.2f) when going out of scope
}
```

[See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1rq4hYdar)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't get much more complicated than what you already have.

```
  template<typename... Ts> struct Context
  {
      std::tuple<Ts...> values;
      std::tuple<Ts&...> refs;
  
      Context(Ts&... ts) : values(ts...), refs(ts...) {}
      ~Context() { refs = values; }
  };
```

You don't need any macros.

```
Context save(x, y, z);
```

Template arguments can be omitted thanks to CTAD.

Comment: damn, why did I not try that :D

Comment: This seems to allow nonsense like Context save(a+b), at least for a and b being such that a+b returns a class type. I'm not sure what `refs` ends up referring to in this case.

Comment: @KevinMartin A reference will not bind to a temporary, so it should not compile.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I was thinking of a const reference which can bind to a temporary. I had just tried implementing something like this first as a two-argument save-and-set of a single variable (SaverClass save(variable, newValue)) without tuples or ..., then switched to the tuple version that only saves but does not change the variable, and was surprised to find it still compiled. Or perhaps I was using the rvalue reference && which can also bind to temporaries, who knows? The intermediate version of the code didn't get checked in anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something called a scope guard. A sketch here :

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename fn_t>
static constexpr bool is_void_noexcept()
{
    return std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<fn_t>()()), void> &&
        noexcept(std::declval<fn_t>()());
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// very simple scope guard implementation

template<typename fn_t>
class scope_guard_t
{
public:
    scope_guard_t(fn_t fn) :
        m_active{ true },
        m_fn{ fn }
    {
        static_assert(is_void_noexcept<fn_t>(), "function must return void and be noexcept");
    }

    void reset() noexcept
    {
        m_active = false;
    }

    ~scope_guard_t()
    {
        if (m_active) m_fn();
    }

private:
    bool m_active;
    fn_t m_fn;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void f(int& value)
{
    scope_guard_t guard{ [&, original_value = value]() noexcept
    {
        value = original_value; // <== here is your reset :)
        std::cout << "scope guard called\n";
    }};

    value = 42;
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int value{ 12 };
    std::cout << value << "\n";
    f(value);
    std::cout << value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to accomplish the OP's desired task, which is to restore the variable to its original value. The code seems to "restore" it to zero, and would need additional complexity to restore the original value.

Comment: Fair enough, modified the lambda capture so it now captures the original value and resets it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` can be simply defined. For the macro, the parameter for `Context` type is hard to extract, hopefully use `auto` is possible.

```cpp
template<typename... Ts>
struct Context {
   std::tuple<Ts...>  savedValues;
   std::tuple<Ts&...> refs;
   Context(Ts&... values)
      : savedValues{values...}, refs{values...} {
   }
   ~Context() {
      refs = savedValues;
   }
};

#define SAVE_CONTEXT( ... )  \
   auto CONCAT( ctx, __LINE__ ) { Context{__VA_ARGS__} }

int main() {
   int  var1 = 1;
   double  var2 = 3.14;
   char  var3 = 'a';
   {
      SAVE_CONTEXT( var1, var2, var3 );
      var1 = 3;
      var2 = 2.72;
      var3 = '0';
   }
   endl( std::cout << var1 << ' ' << var2 << ' ' << var3 ); // restored
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These responses all have a (probably unsolvable) flaw that you have to give a name to an object that you'll never refer to again. The examples here use `save` or `guard`.

Having to pick a name for these objects is a trivial yet irritating coding burden.